# how scroll view up when uidatepicker/pickerview appear similar with keyboard ios

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uidatepicker

I have a screen with several buttons from top to bottom and when they touched, they will show pickerview and uidatepicker. the problem is how to scroll the view if uidatepicker blocked the button.

so i want scroll view working here just like when uikeyboard appear. thanks! :)

ps: i really want to upload the images but my reput don't allow me to do that :)

update:

in the end i use this on my code and the animation looks similar with tpavoiding scroll, here is the code

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5f animations:^{
self.containerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, -120, 320, 308);
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {} ];
```

so containerView will move up 120, and when i click done(toolbar above the uidatepicker) i just make it to normal position.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5f animations:^{
self.containerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 308);
}
completion:^(BOOL finished) {} ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIView animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: duration animations:^{ myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320);} completion:^(BOOL finished) { [self doSomething]; } ];
```